# Pug infite element nesting by iteration

Tags: html, iteration, pug

I've wondered if there is a way to infinitly nest html elements using a pug iteration. The only thing I thought of was an iteration counter dependent indentation for the markup. But I'm not even sure if this is a possible thing. Does somebody know if there is a way to do that?

Heres a little example for clarification:

The following pug markup

```
div
  div 
    div
      div
        div
```

would lead to the following html

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is what I am trying to achieve using an iteration or something in pug to keep the code small, even if we had 10000 elements nested like this.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive [mixin](https://pugjs.org/language/mixins.html) to nest `n` number of elements:

```
mixin nest(n)
  div
    if n-- > 1
      +nest(n)

+nest(10)
```

This will compile to:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <div>
                <div>
                  <div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Obviously makes sense! :)  Thank you, I'm accepting your answer.